# Can higher order derivatives be used in diffusion models?

Tags: generative-model

I remember reading an article about predicting both the first and second derivative in a diffusion model and then using the Taylor method to denoise in each step, to achieve faster convergence. But I can't find it.

Is that even a thing?. Could it be used for image generation?